# how do i make an existing class to singleton?

Tags: spring, spring-bean

i'm new to spring.
i have my class as below in main/module1

```
public class MainClass extends Thread {

protected final SomeClass someclass;

//constructor
public MainClass(SomeClass s) {
super(s.id);
someclass = s;
}

@Override
public void run(){
//some logic
}

@Override
public void interrupt(){
//some logic
}

public static class SomeClass {
//some methods
public MainClass do(){
MainClass mc = new MainClass(this);
mc.do();
return mc;}
}
}
```

what i tried:
created a new class in module2, something like below

```
public class MainClass extends Thread {
protected final MainClass.SomeClass obj;

protected MainClass(MainClass.SomeClass someObject) {
super();
obj = someObject;
}

public static class SomeClass {
private static MainClass mobject = null;

public MainClass do() {
if(mobject==null){
mobject = new MainClass(this);
mobject.do();}
return mobject;}
}
}
```

now, i have auto config class that creates beans of MainClass based on properties.

> now, in my main/module2 package, i want to implement this same class
> as singleton. how do i achieve this? is the approach i took is
> correct?

Comment: someone please answer this.